# How to search for sites having a certain tag?

Tags: support, tags

I want the list of Stack Exchange sites that support a tag, let's say *sun*. How to find a list of all sites that have the sun as one of the tags, instead of searching in all individual sites?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101905/295232

Comment: If you just want a list of sites, consider using a SEDE query like e.g. this one: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/752898/tag-excerpts-networkwide-comparison

Comment: Note that sun in computing is somewhat different to sun in astronomy or space exploration.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300064/152859) gives a nice workaround, probably the best we can do without using SEDE.

Comment: In case a simple list of all posts with a specific tag would do, you could use a filter as mentioned in this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318201/237989

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've modified the SEDE query I mentioned in the comments slightly; [this new SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/926495/tags-networkwide-comparison?tagname=sun) should do the trick. You can click on the entry in the 'Site' column to go to the tag info page on a specific site.

You immediately see 'sun' means something different on computer-related sites than it does for science, as @RobertLongson noted.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to do this is to use the [filters page](https://stackexchange.com/filters) (although this probably wasn't its intended purpose):

[image]

Just select "Just questions tagged with the ____ tag", then "Just these sites ______". You may have to also "show more sites".